# When writing a new c# app to replace a vb6 app, what can be used to replace COM objects?

Tags: c#, com, vb6

### Background:

I have an old vb6 application that I really need to get out of my life.  I love coding in c# and want to make an application to replace the old vb6 application.

The vb6 app has a component app that is installed via IIS and that the main GUI vb6 app connects to for various purposes.  The reason the COM app/components exist are so that everything done is coming from the same source.

Ex: I'm working remotely and need to connect to an FTP server that is only accessible from my works network.  The main GUI app connects to the COM object, issues a command and then that set of components creates the FTP connection from my work network/ip (instead of my home network/ip).

### Question:

In replacing this old application GUI and COM object, what is the best approach in c#?  Should I still use the old `Component Services` that I hate so much?  Or is there a newer, better way of going about this same task?

Comment: Never having used COM objects... could you replace it with some sort of RPC mechanism? The only reason I could see to downvote is that without deep knowledge of COM I don't know what you are trying to accomplish in order to suggest alternatives

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe it's because it's not exactly clear what you're asking for here.  Generally:  there doesn't seem to be anything in what you're saying (GUI to talk via FTP) that implies it even needs COM.  Can you clarify?  COM is generally useful to talk to legacy elements... is there some legacy aspect that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks, I'm not sure.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @ReginaldBlue I 100% did address what you are asking about.  Not sure how I could have been more clear.  I talked about how I need to send a file via FTP from work while being at a different location (home).  It has to do with IP restrictions etc.

Comment: Does anyone think that `.NET Framework Remoting Application` found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/xws7132e(v=vs.100) would be a good approach for me to replace my components?

Comment: What do you mean by "a component app installed via IIS?" how does your vb6 component connects to this component? Are you talking about out-of-process ("Server") COM server hosted by Component Services? If yes, what's IIS doing in there?

Comment: @SimonMourier Sorry, that part I was a little vague on.  Currently I create an application in the `component manager` then I add my components to it (from a DLL).  Then I have IIS setup using MSADC to handle the incoming calls.  I could take IIS out of the equation if I wanted to and it would still work (if I was local on the server running the GUI app).  In the end I just want to build a GUI app that can connect to a remote dll.  When I tell the remote dll to SendFTPFile() as an example, I want it to have the source IP coming from the location of the DLL (office) and NOT the GUI (home).

Comment: Ok. MSADC is totally legacy indeed. However, Component Services (a.k.a COM+ services) can still be used to easily host a COM Server DLL w/o having to write an .exe or use another surrogate host. It's IMHO the easiest way to host COM Server DLL. This includes .NET objects exposed as COM components. If you want to get rid of COM, then you have tons of ways to do inter-process with .NET (.NET Remoting, UDP or TCP Sockets, WCF, ASP.NET WebApi, etc.). Each of this solution in fact opens on another list of choices. The ultimate choice heavily depends on your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about using FTP that would require COM (and certainly writing a GUI in C# does not require COM either).

If I were doing it:

- WPF GUI (Future proof for when WinForms is gone... and gives you a leg up with WinRT which also supports XAML).
- Nuget in an FTP library, like this one:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ftp.dll/

Make sure you separate your GUI from your back-end communications through appropriate interfaces/patterns so you can replace things easily and more "future-proof" your application.

Edit:

So, what you're really after is:  How can I have a GUI front end that talks to a back end via various means?

So, there's lots of answers to that, and it basically boils down to, either:  don't do that, "pick a lane and stick to it", or "Use WCF".

WCF (Windows Communication Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf ) is a back-end server side technology that supports multiple communication protocols simultaneously, but generally allows you to interact between client and server.  SOAP was originally the popular choice, but it also supports Remoting (which you alluded to), you can send attachments via DIME which is then like FTP, or you can roll-your-own and do anything you want (e.g. using Capn Proto (https://capnproto.org/) to send binary messages).

Alternately, if you can get away from trying to do everything, you may want to look into REST instead which is supported by Web API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448365(v=vs.118).aspx ).  This will allow you to send lightweight data back and forth, and is, typically, "the way it's done" these days.

Good luck!

Comment: I think you might be focusing in on the wrong think with this question.  The application and components do many things (not just FTP).  FTP was just a common task/protocol that usually most know about so I used that as an example.  I have to send the data from a specific IP address.  THAT is why I have to use COM in this old vb6 application.  Other that the first sentence I love your answer though!  It will give me something to shoot for.  I have been looking for a reason to get into WPF even though I have avoided it for so long.  Thanks!

Comment: And that's what's confusing about your question.  :-)

Comment: Sorry about that.  Did I say something else in my comment that made the question more clear?  If so I can edit my question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, lots of great info and I have a lot more research to do.  I know one of the operations I have to support is FTP.  Not for me sending data to and from a client and server i develop but in the end my user using my gui needs to send files to a third party FTP server I don't control.  Lots of things to think about.  At this point I have no clue what direction I will go.  But I wanted to be using well known and practiced methods using remote dlls etc.